# Первичная установка или обновление андроид-приложения, как узнать программно?

Tags: android, установка, обновление

В андроид приложении хочу реализовать появление всплывающего окна с информацией об изменениях в новой версии приложения.

Если пользователь обновляет приложение, то хочу выводить всплывающее окно.

При первичной же установке с GooglePlay это окно не должно появляться.

Как можно различить программно первичная установка приложения и обновление?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть такой подход - регистрируем ресивер на переустановку своего приложения:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyAppUpdatedReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

---

```
public class MyAppUpdatedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // этот код будет выполнен после каждой переустановки
        // но при первой установке не вызывается
    }
}
```

Другой вариант: записываем куда-нибудь номер версии и при каждом старте сравниваем с текущим, если изменился - выводим ченжлог

Comment: Другой вариант попробовал изначально (писал в отдельный файл, и пробовал юзал `SharedPreferences`)  но пришлось отсеять из-за особенностей приложения., хотя он тоже рабочий.

Comment: А вот `BroadcastReceiver` работает независимо от точки входа в приложение.

Answer (score 2):

Можно так проверять:

```
public static boolean isFirstInstall() {
try {
    long firstInstallTime =   App.getContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).firstInstallTime;
    long lastUpdateTime = App.getContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).lastUpdateTime;
    return firstInstallTime == lastUpdateTime;
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return true;
}
}



public static boolean isInstallFromUpdate() {
try {
    long firstInstallTime =   App.getContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).firstInstallTime;
    long lastUpdateTime = App.getContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).lastUpdateTime;
    return firstInstallTime != lastUpdateTime;
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Почему то второй метод срабатывает при каждом открытии приложения.

Answer (score 1):

Все очень просто.

**В теории:**

Вы получаете программно текущую версию кода приложения, сохраняете её в `SharedPrefereneces`, и делаете условие, если сохраненная версия соответствует текущей версии, не происходит ничего. То есть, юзер впервые скачал приложение, версия кода у которого равна 1, или пусть 32, и этот номер сохраняется. И как только сохраненный номер кода станет меньше текущего, это будет означать что приложение обновили, тогда выполняется условие вызова диалогового окна например, со списком изменений.

**На практике:**

```
// Реализовываем SharedPreferences
SharedPreferences mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
@SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits") SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mPreferences.edit();

// Получаем текущую версию кода
int versionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;

// Получаем сохраненную версию кода
int lastVersionCode = mPreferences.getInt("update_true", versionCode);

// Если lastVersionCode меньше чем текущий versionCode выполняется условие
if (lastVersionCode < versionCode) {
    // Вызываем диалоговое окно со списком измненений
}

// Сохраняем текущую версию кода
mEditor.putInt("update_true", versionCode).apply();
```

Comment: Хорошая идея, спасибо что детально описали код. Он работает. Единственное что у меня несколько точек входа в приложение с которых заходит пользователь (издержки распределения уровней доступа), потому в данном случае не совсем удобно вешать проверки на несколько активити. Пришлось искать альтернативу.